# Unbalanced paired t-test alternatives? maybe a mixed model regression?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, t-test

I have an experiment at which a varying amount of people between 100 and 500 recieved a blue or red shirt and walked on a main street in different times of the day. I am measuring the time it took for strangers to approach these people (let's assume all of them were approached eventually, and also at each hour there were at least 50 people on the street in each shirt-color group).

I thought first of a paired t-test for the different hours (creating bins for the sum of people on the streat each hour), but as the amount of people is different between the groups, a paired t-test is not an option.

I read that a mixed regression could solve my questions, so I'd like to make sure I'm doing it the right way:

1. shirt color (blue/red) is a fixed effect
2. hour of day (binned amount of people with shirt on the street between 6 and 23) is a random effect
3. the time it took for the people to be approached is the dependent variable

is this the right way? is there another (better) way to do this?

A similar (yet not identical)  problem:
[Multilevel alternative to Paired t-test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222184/multilevel-alternative-to-paired-t-test)

Comment: `but as the amount of people is different between the groups, a paired t-test is not an option` -- well, so you can use an unpaired t-test.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like an excellent candidate for a generalised additive model (GAM). GAMs let you model your data as smooth functions of one or more variables. What this means is that you can capture nonlinear changes over the course of the day within your model. This lets you avoid 1) binning your data, and 2) specifying exactly how it may go up or down during the day.

In your case, I recommend modelling your response as a smooth function of time, with shirt colour as a category (which would have the effect of shifting your smoothed time-dependence up or down).

In R, your code would look like this:

```
library(mgcv)
mod <- gam(response_time ~ shirt_colour + s(time), data = dat)
```

(Note that I'm ignoring some possible complexities you might face but haven't described, such as a big spike at lunchtime. If this happens, it would pose a challenge for any analytical approach, not just GAMs. Such patterns can be addressed in the model, though.)